# Substitute for thread executor pool in Scala

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, akka, akka-stream

My application requires that I have multiple threads running fetching data from various HDFS nodes. For that I am using the thread executor pool and forking threads.
**Forking at :**

```
val pathSuffixList = fileStatuses.getOrElse("FileStatus", List[Any]()).asInstanceOf[List[Map[String, Any]]]
  pathSuffixList.foreach(block => {
    ConsumptionExecutor.execute(new Consumption(webHdfsUri,block))
  })
```

**My class Consumption :**

```
class Consumption(webHdfsUri: String, block:Map[String,Any]) extends Runnable {

      override def run(): Unit = {
        val uriSplit = webHdfsUri.split("\\?")
        val fileOpenUri = uriSplit(0) + "/" + block.getOrElse("pathSuffix", "").toString + "?op=OPEN"
        val inputStream = new URL(fileOpenUri).openStream()
        val datumReader = new GenericDatumReader[Void]()
        val dataStreamReader = new DataFileStream(inputStream, datumReader)
        //        val schema = dataStreamReader.getSchema()
        val dataIterator = dataStreamReader.iterator()
        while (dataIterator.hasNext) {
          println(" data : " + dataStreamReader.next())
        }
      }

    }
```

**ConsumptionExecutor :**

```
object ConsumptionExecutor{

  val counter: AtomicLong = new AtomicLong()

  val executionContext: ExecutorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new ThreadFactory {
    def newThread(r: Runnable): Thread = {
      val thread: Thread = new Thread(r)
      thread.setName("ConsumptionExecutor-" + counter.incrementAndGet())
      thread
    }
  })
  executionContext.asInstanceOf[ThreadPoolExecutor].setMaximumPoolSize(200)

  def execute(trigger: Runnable) {
    executionContext.execute(trigger)
  }

}
```

However I want to use Akka streaming/ Akka actors where in I don't need to give a fixed thread pool size and Akka takes care of everything.
I am pretty new to Akka and the concept of Streaming and actors . Can someone give me any leads in the form of a sample code to fit my use case?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea would be to create a (subclass) instance of [ActorPublisher](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-M3/scala/stream-integrations.html) for each HDFS node that you are reading from, and then `Merge` them in as multiple `Source`s in a [FlowGraph](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-M3/scala/stream-graphs.html).

Something like this pseudo-code, where the details of the `ActorPublisher` sources are left out:

```
val g = PartialFlowGraph { implicit b =>
  import FlowGraphImplicits._
  val in1 = actorSource1
  val in2 = actorSource2
  // etc.

  val out = UndefinedSink[T]
  val merge = Merge[T]

  in1 ~> merge ~> out
  in2 ~> merge
  // etc.
}
```

This can be improved for a collection of actor sources by just iterating over them and adding an edge to the `merge` for each one, but this gives the idea.